# How to select specific columns from a .txt file using perl

Tags: windows, perl, awk

I've recently heard about `awk` and `perl` and I believe that these are great tools for processing raw data files so I want to become familiar with `Perl`.

I thought of playing with a [.txt file](http://pastebin.com/pgSjezdh). In this file, there are some strings at first. What I am trying to do is print in a seperate `.txt` file, some columns(i.e. the 1st and the 4th) without their units.

I see that I must, somehow, use the lines thar are between hyphens(`-`), so that's the algorithm.

The thing is that I don't know how to do it in perl. Any idea or help would be more than welcome!!!

The file has the format

```
 ==================================================================
              Calculation using SRIM-2006
              SRIM version ---> SRIM-2008.04
              Calc. date   ---> December 05, 2013
 ==================================================================

 Disk File Name = SRIM Outputs\Helium in Silicon

 Ion = Helium [2] , Mass = 4.003 amu

 Target Density =  2.3212E+00 g/cm3 = 4.9770E+22 atoms/cm3
 ======= Target  Composition ========
    Atom   Atom   Atomic    Mass    
    Name   Numb   Percent   Percent  
    ----   ----   -------   -------  
     Si     14    100.00    100.00  
 ====================================
 Bragg Correction = 0.00%
 Stopping Units =  MeV / (mg/cm2)
 See bottom of Table for other Stopping units

   Ion        dE/dx      dE/dx     Projected  Longitudinal   Lateral
  Energy      Elec.      Nuclear     Range     Straggling   Straggling
-----------  ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------  ----------
 500.00 keV   1.452E+00  3.238E-03    1.98 um     1891 A      2389 A  
 550.00 keV   1.449E+00  2.999E-03    2.13 um     1921 A      2443 A  
 600.00 keV   1.441E+00  2.795E-03    2.27 um     1951 A      2495 A  
 650.00 keV   1.430E+00  2.619E-03    2.42 um     1979 A      2545 A  
 700.00 keV   1.416E+00  2.466E-03    2.57 um     2007 A      2594 A  
 800.00 keV   1.384E+00  2.211E-03    2.88 um     2084 A      2689 A  
 900.00 keV   1.349E+00  2.007E-03    3.19 um     2160 A      2782 A  
   1.00 MeV   1.312E+00  1.839E-03    3.51 um     2237 A      2874 A  
   1.10 MeV   1.276E+00  1.700E-03    3.84 um     2314 A      2967 A  
   1.20 MeV   1.240E+00  1.581E-03    4.18 um     2392 A      3060 A  
   1.30 MeV   1.206E+00  1.479E-03    4.53 um     2471 A      3153 A  
   1.40 MeV   1.172E+00  1.390E-03    4.89 um     2551 A      3249 A  
   1.50 MeV   1.141E+00  1.312E-03    5.26 um     2633 A      3345 A  
   1.60 MeV   1.111E+00  1.243E-03    5.65 um     2716 A      3444 A  
   1.70 MeV   1.082E+00  1.181E-03    6.04 um     2801 A      3544 A  
   1.80 MeV   1.055E+00  1.126E-03    6.44 um     2888 A      3647 A  
   2.00 MeV   1.005E+00  1.030E-03    7.27 um     3176 A      3858 A  
   2.25 MeV   9.495E-01  9.320E-04    8.37 um     3605 A      4135 A  
   2.50 MeV   9.002E-01  8.522E-04    9.53 um     4031 A      4426 A  
   2.75 MeV   8.564E-01  7.857E-04   10.75 um     4456 A      4732 A  
   3.00 MeV   8.172E-01  7.294E-04   12.04 um     4883 A      5053 A  
   3.25 MeV   7.821E-01  6.811E-04   13.38 um     5312 A      5388 A  
   3.50 MeV   7.503E-01  6.391E-04   14.78 um     5744 A      5737 A  
   3.75 MeV   7.214E-01  6.024E-04   16.24 um     6180 A      6101 A  
   4.00 MeV   6.950E-01  5.698E-04   17.76 um     6619 A      6478 A  
   4.50 MeV   6.486E-01  5.148E-04   20.96 um     8162 A      7272 A  
   5.00 MeV   6.090E-01  4.700E-04   24.38 um     9630 A      8118 A  
-----------------------------------------------------------
 Multiply Stopping by        for Stopping Units
 -------------------        ------------------
  2.3211E+01                 eV / Angstrom
  2.3211E+02                keV / micron  
  2.3211E+02                MeV / mm      
  1.0000E+00                keV / (ug/cm2)
  1.0000E+00                MeV / (mg/cm2)
  1.0000E+03                keV / (mg/cm2)
  4.6637E+01                 eV / (1E15 atoms/cm2)
  4.2914E+00                L.S.S. reduced units
 ==================================================================
 (C) 1984,1989,1992,1998,2008 by J.P. Biersack and J.F. Ziegler
```

The output should contain the data from the six columns without their units.

Comment: Please post some sample input and desired output.

Comment: @fedorqui: Thank you very much for your comment! The sample file is http://pastebin.com/pgSjezdh and the ouptut would be just the columns the next to the other, seperated by tab or space!

Comment: The input file is not homogeneous. Also, note that is good to post some sample input to make the question http://sscce.org/

Comment: I'll edit my question immidiately! Thank's! The file isn't homegenous indeed, that why I thought perl could handle it. Isn't that the case here?

Comment: @Thanos  If you're just beginning, and this is purely to help you kern perl I would start with something much more regular than this.

Comment: @FlyingFrog: It a combination. I need this to be done and given the chance I will have the cahnce to see how it's done on `perl`, which could be very educational.

Comment: @Thanos - I've provided some new code in my answer that will do exactly what you want, but is not in the least bit scalable, so might not be the most helpful learning tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a small text file, one option is to read the file's contents into a string, use a regex to capture the table, and then another regex to capture the vals of cols 1 and 4:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $content = do { local $/; <> };
my ($table) = $content =~ /-----\n(.+?)\n-----/s;

while ( $table =~ /(\S+)\s+([kM]eV).+?(\S+)\s+um/g ) {
    print $2 eq 'keV' ? $1 * 1000 : $1;
    print "\t$3\n";
}
```

Partial output:

```
500000  1.98
550000  2.13
600000  2.27
650000  2.42
700000  2.57
800000  2.88
900000  3.19
1.00    3.51
1.10    3.84
1.20    4.18
1.30    4.53
1.40    4.89
1.50    5.26
...
```

Command-line usage: `>perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

The first line *slurps* the file's content into `$content`.  The second line's regex captures all the text between `-----\n` and `\n-----` (the table), and the captured table's placed into `$table`.  Finally, the last regex globally 'looks for' the column vals (note that the regex uses the columns' units to find them), and `while` they're found, they're `print`ed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Is there a way to multiply specific entries with a number? For instance, the first column has keV and MeV. Is there a way to multiply the firts 7 entries of the 1st column with 1000?

Comment: @Thanos - You're most welcome!  Yes, you can col1 * 1000 for only the keV vals by capturing the units and multiplying that val * 1000 if the capture is keV.  Have updated my answer to reflect this. Note the `expression ? val1 : val2` notation.  This is the [ternary](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator) operator.

Comment: @Kenonsis: Thank you so much for the update. It's working like a charm!!! I need definitely learn `perl` on my own! I believe your code is a very nice educating example!!!

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR>=25 && NR<=51 {print $1, $3, $4, $5, $7, $9 > "output.txt"}' file

$ cat output.txt
500.00 1.452E+00 3.238E-03 1.98 1891 2389
550.00 1.449E+00 2.999E-03 2.13 1921 2443
600.00 1.441E+00 2.795E-03 2.27 1951 2495
650.00 1.430E+00 2.619E-03 2.42 1979 2545
700.00 1.416E+00 2.466E-03 2.57 2007 2594
800.00 1.384E+00 2.211E-03 2.88 2084 2689
900.00 1.349E+00 2.007E-03 3.19 2160 2782
1.00 1.312E+00 1.839E-03 3.51 2237 2874
1.10 1.276E+00 1.700E-03 3.84 2314 2967
1.20 1.240E+00 1.581E-03 4.18 2392 3060
1.30 1.206E+00 1.479E-03 4.53 2471 3153
1.40 1.172E+00 1.390E-03 4.89 2551 3249
1.50 1.141E+00 1.312E-03 5.26 2633 3345
1.60 1.111E+00 1.243E-03 5.65 2716 3444
1.70 1.082E+00 1.181E-03 6.04 2801 3544
1.80 1.055E+00 1.126E-03 6.44 2888 3647
2.00 1.005E+00 1.030E-03 7.27 3176 3858
2.25 9.495E-01 9.320E-04 8.37 3605 4135
2.50 9.002E-01 8.522E-04 9.53 4031 4426
2.75 8.564E-01 7.857E-04 10.75 4456 4732
3.00 8.172E-01 7.294E-04 12.04 4883 5053
3.25 7.821E-01 6.811E-04 13.38 5312 5388
3.50 7.503E-01 6.391E-04 14.78 5744 5737
3.75 7.214E-01 6.024E-04 16.24 6180 6101
4.00 6.950E-01 5.698E-04 17.76 6619 6478
4.50 6.486E-01 5.148E-04 20.96 8162 7272
5.00 6.090E-01 4.700E-04 24.38 9630 8118
```

It gets data from line 25 to 51 and prints the 1st, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 7th and 9th column into  `output.txt` file.

---

#### Update

> I also see that you are using the line numbers. In case a new file,
>   with the same format, but with different number of data comes up, is
>   there another way to do the same, without having to count the lines?

You can check from first `-----------` up to the `-----------------------------------------------------------`:

```
awk '$1~/-----------------------------------------------------------/ {f=0; exit}
     $1~/-----------/ {f=1; next}
     f{print $1, $3, $4, $5, $7, $9 > "output.txt"}' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The thing is, that I cannot use `awk` on windows...

Comment: Then, why do you tag the question with awk? Note also that `awk` can be used in Windows with cygwin.

Comment: With `cygwin`? Oh I didn't know... I am using `MinGW` which doesn't support `awk`... I'll replace `MinGW` with `Cygwin` then and hopefully it will work!!!

Comment: I also see that you are using the line numbers. In case a new file, with the same format, but with different number of data comes up, is there another way to do the same, without having to count the lines?

Comment: @Thanos check my updated answer. It is another way to get the data from this range.

Comment: I tried to run your code, but it seems that it's running for ever... In the mean while, there is an empty file named 25, is created...

Comment: I also replaced `print` with `printf` but it has the same behaviour.

Comment: @Thanos strange, it works perfectly to me. Which version of my answer are you using?

Comment: What's the name of your file? Just to make sure the input and output file are the same.

Comment: It's `test.txt`. I am using `awk 'NR>=25 && NR<=51 {printf $1, $3, $4, $5, $7, $9 > "output.txt"}' test.txt`(also `print` instead of `printf`). I also tried `awk 'NR>=25 && NR<=51 {print $1, $3, $4, $5, $7, $9}' test.txt >output.txt` but again it seems that it's running forever... Note also that this code `awk '$6=="um" {x=1; if ($2=="keV") x=0.001; printf "%12s%12s%12s%12s\n", x*$1, $5, $7, $9}' data.txt` works...

Comment: Note my solution is not like that, I updated it the day I answered for the first time. The redirection is inside the `{}`: `awk 'NR>=25 && NR<=51 {print $1, $3, $4, $5, $7, $9 > "output.txt"}' file`

Comment: The previous code you gave me, is the one that I am really using!

Comment: OK so give a try to the one I suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should do what you want, and you should be able to use it on files of different lengths, as long as the numbers you want are inbetween `--------`:

```
my $infile = 'in.txt';
open my $input, '<', $infile or die "Can't open to $infile: $!";

my $count = 0;
while (<$input>){
    chomp;
    $count++ if /^-----/;
    s/[a-zA-Z]//g;
    print "$_\n" if $count == 1 and ! /^-----/;
    next;
}
```

Briefly, this will read your file line by line. Every time it sees a line that matches the regex `/^-----/` it will +1 to a count variable.

`s/[a-zA-Z]//g` will remove any letter from the lines.

It will then print out the whole line if the count variable equals 1 and the line doesn't match `/^-----/`. Thus, it will not print out lines before `/^-----/` (as count == 0) or after the second `/^-----/` (as count now == 2).

It's probably not the most elegant way of going about it, but it should work and will be easy enough for you to get your head around.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! In the file you can see for instance, that the real data are from line 25 till 51. In line 24 and line 52 you can see that there is a group of hyphens. So the "treasure" data are between those groups of hyphens.

Comment: So all you want to do is extract that data between lines 24 - 53?

Comment: I want to extract and print in a sepperate file the lines from line 25 till line 51, withous the strings between those numbers;the units that is.

Comment: I notice that you are using the line numbers. If a new file comes up, with longer data, but the same format, is there a way to use the hyphens as a pointer, that will indicate the start and the end of the data.

Comment: I am tryiong to use your code... How is the syntax? I am using `perl data.pl`...How to tell it which is going to be the input? I tried to replace `input` in your code with `test.txt` and I also used `perl data.pl test.txt` but it doesn't seem to do anything at all...

Comment: I just forgot to add `my $infile = 'in.txt';
open my $input, '<', $infile or die "Can't open to $infile: $!";`

Comment: I replaced `25 .. 24` with `"-----------  ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------  ----------" .. "-----------------------------------------------------------";` but it doesn't do the job...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! What does `s/[a-zA-Z]//g;` do exactly?

Comment: @Thanos  - it substitutes any character between a-z and A-Z with nothing (essentially deletes them) thereby leaving you with just digits in your columns. If this answers your question please select it as the right answer to close the question...

Answer (score 1):

From windows command line:

```
perl -F'-\s+-' -ane "print if (@F == 6 ... /--/) and !/--/ and s/ [a-z]+//gi" file
```

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

> If you don't want it to test the right operand until the next evaluation, as in sed, just use three dots ("...") instead of two. In all other regards, "..." behaves just like ".." does.

UPDATE:

```
perl -lane "print qq{@F[0,2,3,4,6,8]} if (/^-/ ... /^-/) and !/^-/" file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! The thing is that I want to print, only numbers. Is there a way to get rid of the units, next to numbers?

Comment: What is the purpose of `-F'-\s-'`? Is that just a way to count the fields of headers? I seem to get the right result with a simple flip-flop: `perl -nlwe"print if /^-/ ... /^-/ and !/^-/"`

Comment: @TLP yes, it is just one of possible approaches; it follows header more accurately.

Comment: @mpapec: I used `perl -F'-\s+-' -ane "print if (@F == 6 ... /--/) and !/--/ and s/ [a-z]+//gi" test.txt >columns.txt` and it worked fine! Now, I am trying to understand your code... If I want to print let's say, column 1 and 4 without the units, how will your code change?

Comment: @Thanos check update; drop indexes for `@F` to filter out columns

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

open my $f, "<", 'input' or die("$!");

# find the data (read as long as no dashes)
while (<$f> !~ /^-----/) {}

# process the data (until there are dashes)
while (<$f>) {
    last if /^------/;  # ends with dashes
    my @v = split;
    print join(" ", @v[0,4]), "\n";
}

close $f;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I suppose I have to save your code in a file(i.e. data.perl), compile it(how?) and execute it?

Comment: just do `perl file.pl` after you save the code into `file.pl`. No compilation needed. Also change the name of the input file (`input` above) if needed.

Comment: My file is named `test.txt`. I replaced `input` with, `test`, `test.txt` but I get the erros `No such file or directory at data.pl line 4`. The I thought of replacing `'input'` with `test` or `test.txt` but again the same error, occurs. Note that the `.pl` and the `.txt` are on the same directory.

Comment: it should be test.txt: `open my $f, "<", 'test.txt' or die("$!");`. If you still get the error make sure you are running perl from within the same directory `perl file.pl`. Test the file name with `ls test.txt` before executing the script.

Comment: I changed the `input` accordingly, I used `dir test.txt`(I am on windows) and it seems that the file is indeed there... But I still get that error...